# P12 creation instance

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

first time posting, long time viewer. I am having a problem with my homework assignment. I have looked on the web and stackoverflow, but have yet to find out why my line of code is not working. This is what I have tried.

```
C:\Openssl\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in C:\Users\jokesrfunny\Desktop\jokescert.pem -inkey   
C:\Users\jokesrfunny\Desktop\jokeskey.pem -out c:\tools\daacert.p12 -name jokesrfunny
```

this comes back with the error `unable to lead certificates` and `unable to write 'random state'`

In addition to this I have reference these websites for help and still can't find out what going on.